# Black spots on new growth basil leaves

Tags: basil

I potted some basil plants 2 weeks ago and they have been doing well and the overall plants have looked healthy. A couple of days ago I noticed some small black dots on some of the top leaves. I removed them and today I noticed more black spots appearing. They seem to only be appearing on the new growth leaves and the rest of the plant continues to look healthy. This situation does not match descriptions I have read from online searching as none talk about only the new growth leaves being impacted. Did I just catch a fungal infection early perhaps? I would have thought a fungal infection would impact the whole plant. I am attaching a picture to try to show things. I apologize that it is not a great picture, but I only thought to take one after plucking off the impacted leaves. My hope was to show the spots and that it is the tiny, new-growth leaves that are impacted. [image]Any real life experience with something similar would be appreciated. I can't be the only person with this experience, right?

Comment: Theres information [here](https://www.gardeningchannel.com/black-spots-on-basil-leaves/).  I don't want to plagiarize and copy it here as my answer.